# ListPreference with Theming function

Tags: java, android

I have an android app project which has a settings. I added a ListPreference with 4 Options to theme the Settings, but when i select any option of the ListPreference, only the last option of the ListPreference is applied. I wanted that all the options applies the different themes that i have provided in the /res/values/style.xml.  How i can solve this?

here are my java sources for settings;
[Settings.java](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26396170/)

[SettingThemeUtils.java](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26396171/)

Comment: I see that you are calling all the four methods `onPreferenceChange`. Please call the specified method based on the theme selected.

Comment: @Chithra, Does it mean i have to write the onPreferenceChange separately for each theme?

Comment: You have to handle it in switch case according to your conditions

Comment: yes as per Vrushali's comment, you can use the condition check for the theme selected and apply it accordingly.

Comment: thank you guys, my question is solved.